# How to use Angular pipe in regular Javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using a highlight pipe in Angular's appComponent to highlight search text displayed in the `router-outlet` from another component but I don't know how to use the pipe in a component (not in a template).

What I currently have in `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HighlightPipe } from './shared/highlight-pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [ HighlightPipe ]
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private highlight: HighlightPipe) {}

  startSearch(searchTerm: string) {
    if (!searchTerm) {
      return;
    }
    const content = document.getElementById('content');
    if (content) {
      const mainContent = content.children;

      for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        **content[i].innerHTML = 'content[i].innerHTML | this.highlight: searchTerm';** <-- here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My `app.component.html`:

```
<app-header (searchEvent)="startSearch($event)"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My `highlight-pipe.ts`:

```
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'highlight' })
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: string, search): string {
    let pattern = search.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');
    pattern = pattern.split(' ').filter((t) => {
      return t.length > 0;
    }).join('|');
    const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');

    return search ? text.replace(regex, (match) => `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`) : text;
  }
}
```

So (predictably) my output currently just repeatedly prints the string `content[i].innerHTML | this.highlight: searchTerm` in the `<router-outlet>`

I've seen other articles that talk about using *ngFor but *ngFor is used in a template. But in my case, when someone tries to do a search in the header (not App) component, the header component simply emits the `searchEvent` event that is then received in the `AppComponent` template, which triggers `startSearch` in `AppComponent`... so I have to use the pipe in `AppComponent` instead of in the header.

Is it possible to use a pipe in a plain JS `for` loop in a component instead of in a template in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

With the pipe added to your constructor:

```
constructor(private highlight: HighlightPipe) {}
```

Then you can use:

```
content[i].innerHTML = this.highlight(content[i].innerHTML, "searchTerm")
```

Comment: this works great. just needed to call the transform method on the pipe:

```content[i].innerHTML = this.pipe.transform(content[i].innerHTML, "searchTerm")```

Comment: also had to add the pipe to `providers` in `@Component` like so:

`@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [ HighlightPipe ]
})`

Sorry, formatting not so pretty in the comments section...